# Access to KeePass database from different devices

Tags: networking, keepass

I use a PC with Windows 7 and now an iPad air, latest model. How can I access my keepass.kdbx file from the iPad and/or iPhone 4? a) within the home network, b) in public networks via WiFi or cellular.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options. You can remotely log into your PC (using LogMeIn, GoToMyPC, or something like that). Or, you can use the Mini KeePass app (available in the Apple app store) to open the .kdbx file.

I use the latter option; we use Dropbox Mini KeePass to access the .kdbx files from anywhere. It works fine; you just have to reload the database from the iOS Dropbox app by hand, because changes won't import to Mini KeePass automatically (yet).

Answer (score 0):

You could also try KyPass: it supports dropbox AND two way automatic synchronization.